# Is there an algorithm for detecting odd values relative to set of data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-structures, artificial-intelligence, handler

I want to develop an algorithm that makes an action if it detects that some numbers are odd relative to another array of numbers and each number has a date. Those numbers can vary across the day, but the rate of change of these numbers is not necessarily related.

For example,
The data can be

```
    [
      {number: 200, date: '12:00'},
      {number: 250, date: '12:02'},
      {number: 180, date: '12:04'},
      {number: 500, date: '12:06'}
    ]
```

and the array that I want to test is

```
    [
      {number: 400, date: '12:08'},
      {number: 50, date: '12:10'}
    ]
```

I gather these data for a defined time interval (the above interval is two minutes)
I want to detect if the data falls as time passes, but it can't be directly measured with previous data as it's not consistent and it can fall and rise but I want it to check on the long term.

My Question is what is the approach that I should pursue? Do I have to train a model for that task? If so, what approach should I implement?
I was thinking of writing some hard coded rules that measures the average and compares the data with a threshold. But it wasn't effective on large sets of data as it is not consistent as I stated.

If you have any helpful resources that can help I would be very thankful.

P.S. The above data is not real.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the connection between the two arrays? From your question, I understand that you want to detect if a given number series is approximately decreasing. Where does the second series come into play?

Answer (score 1):

You want an outlier detection which is only searching for decreases.

I propose to create a kernel which predicts the next value based on the recent ones.  See [Gaussian process regression tutorial | Jupyter nbviewer](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/SheffieldML/notebook/blob/master/GPy/basic_gp.ipynb) for starters.  The kernel can give you a prediction as well as a confidence margin.  If your actual value is more than a certain distance below the allowed confidence margin of the prediction, you can call that an outlier in the negative direction and react on it:

Diagram of a confidence margin:

[image]